# How to represent empty char in Java Character class

Tags: java

I want to represent an empty character in Java as  `""` in String...

Like that `char ch = an empty character;`

Actually I want to replace a character without leaving space.

I think it might be sufficient to understand what this means: no character not even space.

Comment: Show an example of the replace operation you want to perform.

Comment: @rahulsri I can't see the code you are referring to.

Comment: I think that OP wants to perform `String.replace(' ', EMPTY_CHARACTER)` to have the same effect as `String.replace(" ", "")`. I.e. remove all spaces.

Answer (score 174):

You may assign `'\u0000'` (or 0).
For this purpose, use [`Character.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MIN_VALUE).

```
Character ch = Character.MIN_VALUE;
```

Comment: What does `'\0'` exactly mean? @AVD

Comment: @cinnamontoast - Its a [null char literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: A null char literal is still a character and takes space in storage.

Comment: The question asks for a way to represent 'no characters'.  While the null character is useful in many situations, it is still a character in its own right, so cannot be the answer to this question.  The correct answer, already given by user3001, is to use Java's boxed Character reference type and give it 'null' value when 'no character' is needed.

Comment: @Augmental The `null` literal denote `missing` object (Reference variable doesn't have object reference).

Comment: @AVD Yes, and rahulsri asks how to represent a missing character. So a null Character reference fits.

Comment: OP wants to perform `String.replace(' ', EMPTY_CHARACTER)` to have the same effect as `String.replace(" ", "")` your answer will not solve his problem. The correct answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/37683750/480894

Answer (score 138):

`char` means exactly one character. You can't assign zero characters to this type.

That means that there is no char value for which `String.replace(char, char)` would return a string with a diffrent length.

Comment: Three years after the fact, someone finally gave a correct and complete answer.

Comment: This is a very accurate answer.

Answer (score 45):

As Character is a class deriving from Object, you can assign null as "instance":

```
Character myChar = null;
```

Problem solved ;)

Comment: This is a correct solution and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Although this does not answer the OP, it's what I was looking for.

Comment: The MOST correct answer is "it cannot be done". This is the nearest you can get.

Comment: Character is, but char isn't.

Comment: LOL: I have Java throwing a null pointer exception when I assign null to Character

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552017/why-does-this-code-give-a-null-pointer-exception-i-thought-character-class-coul

Answer (score 17):

As `chars` can be represented as Integers (ASCII-Codes), you can simply write:

```
char c = 0;
```

The 0 in ASCII-Code is `null`.

Comment: 0 as a UTF-16 code unit (`char`) is the complete UTF-16 encoding for the Unicode codepoint U+0000. Any similarity to some other character set or character encoding is irrelevant. UTF-16 is what Java uses.

Answer (score 16):

An empty String is a wrapper on a `char[]` with no elements. You can have an empty `char[]`. But you cannot have an "empty" `char`. Like other primitives, a `char` has to have a value.

You say you want to "replace a character without leaving a space".

If you are dealing with a `char[]`, then you would create a new `char[]` with that element removed.

If you are dealing with a `String`, then you would create a new `String` (String is immutable) with the character removed.

Here are some samples of how you could remove a char:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String s = "abcdefg";
    int index = s.indexOf('d');

    // delete a char from a char[]
    char[] array = s.toCharArray();
    char[] tmp = new char[array.length-1];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, tmp, 0, index);
    System.arraycopy(array, index+1, tmp, index, tmp.length-index);
    System.err.println(new String(tmp));

    // delete a char from a String using replace
    String s1 = s.replace("d", "");
    System.err.println(s1);

    // delete a char from a String using StringBuilder
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    sb.deleteCharAt(index);
    s1 = sb.toString();
    System.err.println(s1);

}
```

Comment: Apart from replace() solution other two will replace just the first occurrence of the character and not all.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to replace a character in a String without leaving any empty space then you can achieve this by using StringBuilder. String is immutable object in java,you can not modify it.

```
String str = "Hello";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb.deleteCharAt(1); // to replace e character
```

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for this. Simply set the `char c = 0;` and it works perfectly. Try it.

For example, if you are trying to remove duplicate characters from a String , one way would be to convert the string to char array and store in a hashset of characters which would automatically prevent duplicates.

Another way, however, will be to convert the string to a char array, use two  for-loops and compare each character with the rest of the string/char array (a Big O on N^2 activity), then for each duplicate found just set that char to 0..

...and use `new String(char[])` to convert the resulting char array to string and then sysout to print (this is all java btw). you will observe all chars set to zero are simply not there and all duplicates are gone. long post, but just wanted to give you an example.

so yes set `char c = 0;` or if for char array, set `cArray[i]=0` for that specific duplicate character and you will have removed it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. "" is the literal for a string, which contains *no* characters. It does not contain the "empty character" (whatever you mean by that).

Answer (score 4):

In java there is nothing as *empty character literal*, in other words, '' has no meaning unlike "" which means a *empty String literal*

The closest you can go about representing empty character literal is through zero length char[], something like:

```
char[] cArr = {};         // cArr is a zero length array
char[] cArr = new char[0] // this does the same
```

If you refer to String class its default constructor creates a empty character sequence using `new char[0]`

Also, using Character.MIN_VALUE is not correct because it is not really empty character rather smallest value of type character.

I also don't like `Character c = null;` as a solution mainly because jvm will throw NPE if it tries to un-box it. Secondly, null is basically a reference to nothing w.r.t reference type and here we are dealing with primitive type which don't accept null as a possible value.

Assuming that in the string, say str, OP wants to replace all occurrences of a character, say 'x', with empty character '', then try using:

```
str.replace("x", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char ch = Character.MIN_VALUE;
```

The code above will initialize the variable `ch` with the minimum value that a char can have (i.e. `\u0000`).

Answer (score 1):

this is how I do it.

```
char[] myEmptyCharArray = "".toCharArray();
```

Comment: That's not an empty character.  It is a zero length character array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
mystring.replace(""+ch, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

String before = EMPTY_SPACE+TAB+"word"+TAB+EMPTY_SPACE

Where
EMPTY_SPACE = " "  (this is String)
TAB         = '\t' (this is Character)

String after = before.replaceAll(" ", "").replace('\t', '\0')
means
after = "word"

Answer (score 0):

You can only re-use an existing character. e.g. `\0` If you put this in a String, you will have a String with one character in it.

---

Say you want a `char` such that when you do

```
String s = 
char ch = ?
String s2 = s + ch; // there is not char which does this.
assert s.equals(s2);
```

what you have to do instead is

```
String s = 
char ch = MY_NULL_CHAR;
String s2 = ch == MY_NULL_CHAR ? s : s + ch;
assert s.equals(s2);
```

Comment: What do you mean `it not worked`? DO you mean it doesn't compile? In that case it would be `char ch = '\0';` or `char ch = 0;`

Comment: @rahulsri All characters are characters and there is no character which is not a character. You need to work out what your real requirement is and try to solve it a different way.  The `nul` character is one of the many special characters which indicates its a character which is not really there, but it is itself still a character.

Comment: "If god can do anything, can god create a rock even he cannot lift?"  Its similar to the question; Can you create a character which is not a character?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\b` operator (the backspace escape operator) in the second parameter

```
String test= "Anna Banana";

System.out.println(test); //returns Anna Banana<br><br>
System.out.println(test.replaceAll(" ","\b")); //returns AnnaBanana removing all the spaces in the string
```

Comment: xD ... amusing things will result if trying to use thus mangled (yes, mangled, mauled, disfigured) string as part of e.g. file name.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, using below code solved my problem.

```
Char.MIN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

The highest voted answer does **NOT** represent an empty char, it is still a character, to be more precise a **CONTROL** character which can be represented by:

```
Character ascii = 0; // ASCII
Character unicode = '\u0000'; //UTF-16, which is also what Java use
Character min = Character.MIN_VALUE;
```

#### The [Null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (The important bits)

> The null character (also null terminator) is a control character with
> the value zero.[1][2][3][4] It is present in many character sets,
> including those defined by the Baudot and ITA2 codes, ISO/IEC 646 (or
> ASCII), the C0 control code, the Universal Coded Character Set (or
> Unicode), and EBCDIC. It is available in nearly all mainstream
> programming languages.[5] It is often abbreviated as NUL (or NULL,
> though in some contexts that term is used for the null pointer). In
> 8-bit codes, it is known as a null byte.
>
> Today the character has much more significance in the programming
> language C and its derivatives and in many data formats, where it
> serves as a reserved character used to signify the end of a string,[6]
> often called a null-terminated string.[7] This allows the string to be
> any length with only the overhead of one byte;

#### [char](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> The char data type is a **single 16-bit Unicode character**. It has a
> minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or
> 65,535 inclusive).

#### [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html)

> The Character class wraps a value of the primitive type char in an
> object. An object of class Character contains a single field whose
> type is char. In addition, this class provides a large number of
> static methods for determining a character's category (lowercase
> letter, digit, etc.) and for converting characters from uppercase to
> lowercase and vice versa.

In a nutshell, in Java, there is no empty character literal.