# What is the Character equivalent of the String "" (blank String)?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to represent empty char in Java Character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534178/how-to-represent-empty-char-in-java-character-class)

I am using the replace function as defined in java.lang.String, and I tried using "\0" as the equivalent for "" (blank String) but it adds a space not a blank string.

Is there a Character equivalent for a blank String?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534178/how-to-represent-empty-char-in-java-character-class

Comment: What is the code you're running? Are you just trying to delete parts that match your regular expression?

Comment: Can you please post your code here ? So we can know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your string don't contains characters. That means you can't get equivalent.

Comment: I will stop doing that from now on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "empty character". A `char` is a value-type, so it has to have a value. An absence of a value is the absence of a `char` - which is why you can have empty strings (i.e. "no characters") and a nullable char, but not an "empty char".

Anyway, the `String.replace(char, char)` method is meant to substitute one character for another. This operation is very simple because it means that a single block of known size has to be allocated. Whereas `String.replaceAll(string,string)` is a considerably more complicated method to implement, which is why they're different.

Unfortunately there is no `String.replace(char,string)` method - but I hope you can understand why.

Comment: I understand now. Maybe I should try a different method than String.replace(char, char).

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many blank `String`s in a given `String`... how many "nothings" are between `'a'` and `'b'` in `"ab"`? It's like dividing by zero!

Answer (score 1):

I supose you want to replace "something" with "", you can't do it the other way around...

```
       String ou="test";
       ou = ou.replace("t", "");
       System.out.println(ou);
```

the output will be: `es`

with the `char` version of replace this will not work as '' is not a valid `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [String.replace(char,char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)  if you want to remove characters. There is no empty character. That method will never change the length of the string, it just replaces a character with another character

You have to use [String.replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (or `replaceFirst`)

```
"ababababa".replaceAll("a", ""); // returns "bbbb"
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, but notice that there is a `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`, so you should be able to call `String.replace` with a string as the first argument and "" as the second argument.