# Both null and empty char are equal in java

Tags: java, database, null, char

I have doubt while taking a `null` or empty `char` check in Java. Is both have to be checked in any way.

For example in database the variable length for `Char` is 1 . It will allow `null` as well. So if you have empty char does it mean `null`? or we have to check as

```
if(someObject.getSomeCharValue()=='' && someObject.getSomeCharValue()==null) {
    //true
}
else{
    //dont compile
}
```

Comment: you could check if the length is greater than `0` instead

Comment: Is `getSomeCharValue()` returning a `char` or `Character`? `char` can't be `null`. `Character`, it's boxed object, can. Also, the default for `char` is `\u0000`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen char primitive.

Comment: char primitive can't be null as well as it can't be empty. Just tried it myself and it doesn't compile

Comment: @ArthurEirich in which java version you compiled i mean VM version?

Comment: `char` can't be `null` since it is primitive type. Also there is no such a thing as empty char `''` in Java. But even if previous statements would be false and you could get `null` or `''` then char can't be `null` AND `''` at the same time so your condition doesn't make sense.

Comment: If the value is not present in database, what value do you pass to `someCharValue` variable?

Comment: @BelieveToLive my java.vm.version is '24.71-b01' and I use java '1.7.0_71'

Comment: Your code can't compile for `someObject.getSomeCharValue()==''` since there is no `''` in Java. If `someObject.getSomeCharValue()==null` part compiles then it means that result of `getSomeCharValue` is wrapper type `Character`, not primitive `char` (as they can't be `null`s so `==null` would not compile here). In that case you can check for null like you are doing it now, or check against default value of char which is `'\u0000'` which can be also written as `'\0'` or simply `0` (char is also numeric type). In that case you should also remember to use OR operator, not AND.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

char has no value with `''`. In char, [null character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909333/whats-the-default-value-of-char) ([or empty char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534178/how-to-represent-empty-char-in-java-character-class)) is `\0` or `\u0000`. You can't check with `''` or `null`.

For example if you declare a char like this:

```
char c = '';//compilation error here
```

or

```
char c = null;//compilation error here
```

so if you want to check whether a char is null, then you need to use the following code:

```
char c = '\0';
if (c == '\0') System.out.print("char is null");//if(c == '\u0000') also can be possible
else System.out.print("char is not null");
```

Comment: `if (c == '\0' || c == '\u0000')` doesn't make much sense since as you already mentioned `'\0'` and `'\u0000'` are equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(someObject.getSomeCharValue()=='' && someObject.getSomeCharValue()==null)
```

both `someObject.getSomeCharValue()==''` and `someObject.getSomeCharValue()==null` are compilation error.

if there is no value in the DB that means it is null but not empty char.

There is nothing called empty char (`''`) in Java.
But there is empty string (`""`).

Comment: Does this answer OP question?

Comment: so how to handle null?

Comment: @BelieveToLive, If the value is not present in database, what value do you pass to `someCharValue` variable?

Comment: @NamanGala what if I get the value directly from the table into the someCharValue value?

Comment: @BelieveToLive, can you sysout the value and check what it is printing?

Comment: From the DB we will get only String not char even if its size is 1. so before you get the char you can do null check with that string. We cant null check the char.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Empty char](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77578773/4982691)

```
//Empty character literal does not exist in Java.
char c = ''; //does not compile
```

#### A [Null Literal in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.8)

> The null type has one value, the null reference, represented by the
> null literal null, which is formed from ASCII characters.

is different from the

#### [Null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)

> The null character (also null terminator) is a control character with
> the value zero.
>
> Today the character has much more significance in the programming
> language C and its derivatives and in many data formats, where it
> serves as a reserved character used to signify the end of a string,[6]
> often called a null-terminated string.

[Excellent article about Null in Java](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/curly-braces-java-null)

Answer (score -2):

Empty chars are not null. They don't just hold any value.

Yes. You should check both if your column allow nulls. Also, your code might give you `NullPointerException` since you are first checking for empty char and then for null. Better to use below

```
if(someObject.getSomeCharValue()==null || someObject.getSomeCharValue()=='' )
```