# Codename One - String replace with empty character

Tags: codenameone

I like to normalize the phone numbers I get from the contacts in the local phone book. To do that, I want to remove any spaces, dashes, plus signs etc from the number.

CN1 only offers the `String.replace(oldchar, newchar)` function, instead of String operations. From this post, 
[How to represent empty char in Java Character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534178/how-to-represent-empty-char-in-java-character-class/8534309), this should be the way to go:

```
primaryPhoneNumber = primaryPhoneNumber.replace(' ', Character.MIN_VALUE);
```

however, this approach has several implications.

1. the char in the console output looks like a space, but its not. its a string terminator.

`+49 234-63446
0 234 63446`

2. when using this normalized string literal, including the `Character.Min_Value` in a database, the database query involving this string crashes:
   `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00`

How to properly remove spaces and other chars and replace them with a "nothing" `character`?

Comment: There's no "nothing character", you need the empty string as shown in the answer (pls accept it when it solved the problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String p = StringUtils.replaceAll(phone, " ", "");
```